# How can we refactor the nested ternary operator in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was refactoring legacy react code and came across this code containing nested ternary operator:

```
const categoriesList = getCategoryById(store, params[param])
        ? getSubcategoriesToDisplay(store, params[param]).length > 0
          ? [
              getCategoryById(store, params[param]),
              ...getSubcategoriesToDisplay(store, params[param]),
            ]
          : [getCategoryById(store, params[param])]
        : getCategoriesForOfferPage(store);
```

The question is is there a way to make it more readable by refactoring.

Comment: "is there a way to make it more readable by refactoring" - Yes, there is. Have you tried this on your own already? Is there an issue with your conversion? An error? Something else? [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [Don't repeat yourself (DRY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: @DrewReese, I tried using if statement instead of ternary but the code still seems unreadable.

Comment: Please do share what you've tried.

Comment: If your code works, you may want to try ask this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you are repeating a lot of function calls. the first thing I would do is to remove that redundancy by storing the calls results on local variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
let result;
const getCategoryResults = getCategoryById(store, params[param]);
const getSubCategoryResults = getSubcategoriesToDisplay(store, params[param]);
if(getCategoryResults){
    result = getSubCategoryResults.length ? [...getCategoryResults, ...getSubCategoryResults] : [...getCategoryResults];
} else {
    result = getCategoriesForOfferPage(store);
}
```